# Need help with pushbutton on atmega8

Tags: avr, atmega, c

This is what I have:

Atmega 8 wired for programming, confirmed working, programmer is my power supply.
2 leds connected via 470Ohm pull up reisistors to ports PORTB0, PORTB1 and to GROUND, working.
Pushbutton wired directly from VCC to PORT7D. My problem is that pressing button doesn't do anything. I have measured voltage levels at PORT7D and it is 4.96V when I press the button, otherwise it is zero.
Please find the program below and help me:

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int
main (void)
{
    DDRB = 0xFF;
    DDRD = 0x00;


    while(1) 
    {

        if( (PORTD & (1<<PORTD7)) == 1){  
        PORTB =   (1 <<PORTB1);
        _delay_ms(200);
        PORTB = (1 << PORTB0) ;
        _delay_ms(200);
        }else{ PORTB=0xff;}
    }
}
```

Comment: And how did you configure PORTD?

Comment: Dear Ignacio,
I suppose it is configured as Input as my code says.

Answer (score 1):

> Pushbutton wired directly from VCC to PORT7D.

There's one problem. When the button is pushed, the input is high. When the button is released, the input is **floating**. This is bad.

Configure the internal pullup on the pin, and then tie the button to ground. The input will be low when the button is pushed, and high when released.

> ```
> if( (PORTD & (1<<PORTD7)) == 1)
> ```

And there's two more. The input value is on `PINx`, not `PORTx`. And that equality check is erroneous.

```
if (PIND & _BV(PD7))
```

Comment: Please help me with configuring internal pull up resistor because i can't find anything on the internet, only arduino stuff. Btw, It's constantly 0 when i measure it. Thanks!

Comment: DDRx&=~(1<<PDy); PORTx|=(1<<PDy); x is your port, y is the pin #. Sets pin to input and pullup high.

Comment: @zarcel: It's in the datasheet, right on the third page of the "I/O Ports" section, in a table conveniently captioned "Port Pin Configurations".

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to hook up a switch to the AVR is like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgNBci.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Lets say this is pin 3 on port B, so the code would look like this:

```
DDRB&=~(1<<PB3); // Set pin to input
PORTB|=(1<<PB3); // Pullup resistor high
```